# Why is my div not hiding slowly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div containing a table wrapped in a div so parent child relation, I am displaying and hiding the div on click of a text title(table display:hidden initially). My logic works, I can get the table to show and hide on click however, when I pass hide millisecond values, the table still disappears instantly. Here is my structure.

```
var ctdown = false;
jQuery(".table-dropdown").click(function () {
    var table_height = $(".table-dropdown div").show().height()+20;
    $(".table-dropdown div").hide();
    if (ctdown) {
        jQuery(this).animate({
            height: "20px"
        }, 500, function () {
            $(".table-dropdown div").hide(1000000);
        });
    }
    else {
        jQuery(this).animate({
            height: table_height
        }, 500, function () {

        });
        jQuery(".table-dropdown div").show();
    }
    ctdown = !ctdown;
});
```

I put in 100000 just to test if it was actually doing anything, which it is not. Any suggestions? Is there some basic principle here that I am over looking? Thanks!

UPDATE!
I derived an answer from the marked answer in the post and another member who's answer was removed for some reason. Here is my final solution. Thank you to all that helped, greatly appreciate it!

```
var ctdown = false;
$(".table-dropdown").click(function () {
if (ctdown) {
    $(this).animate({
        height: "20px"
    }, 500, function () {
        $("div", this).hide().fadeOut(500);
    });
}
else {
    var table_height = $("div", this).show().height()+20;
    $("div", this).hide();
    $(this).animate({
        height: table_height
    }, 500, function () {

    });
    $("div", this).show();
}
ctdown = !ctdown;
});
```

Comment: You're setting it to hide over a span of `1000000`ms?! That's over 16 minutes! It'd be moving at a snail's pace. Change the value to something lower and try again

Comment: try `.slideDown()` and `.slideUp()`

Comment: Also, why are you changing between `jQuery(...)` and `$(...)`? They're the same. Is the `$(".table-dropdown div").hide()` method is copied in? You can use `$` in like in that line, instead of having to write `jQuery(...)` :)

Comment: @GeoffJames, I guess he is new to jQuery/Javascript - it's much better to say they are the same instead of write what you did!

Comment: Thanks @Dekel. Just re-read my comment and sounded a lot worse than it should have (sorry). I've edited to read a little friendlier

Comment: @Geoff James   as I mentioned in the post this was for testing purposes only, it is hiding at lightning fast speed therefore I know my hide duration is not being accounted for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) or [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) for that.

In you code this could be:

```
var ctdown = false;

jQuery(".table-dropdown").click(function () {

    var table_height = $(".table-dropdown div").show().fadeIn(500).height()+20;
    $(".table-dropdown div").hide().fadeOut(500);

        if (ctdown) {
            jQuery(this).animate({
                height: "20px"
            }, 500, function () {
        $(".table-dropdown div").hide().fadeOut(500);
            });
        }
        else {
            jQuery(this).animate({
                height: table_height
            }, 500, function () {

            });
        jQuery(".table-dropdown div").show().fadeIn(500);
        }
        ctdown = !ctdown;
    });
```

Comment: Still disappearing instantly with the fadeOut.

Comment: i changed the example slightly i didn´t seen the first show and hide

Comment: @willPasternak still disappearing instantly

Comment: Your fadeout answer worked best. I used your advice with another answer posted here however it seems they have removed their answer? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to remove the line that hide the div in this block?

```
var table_height = $(".table-dropdown div").show().height()+20;
$(".table-dropdown div").hide();
```

I have tested that this .hide will hide the div and ignores your second .hide()

Edit 1 -
Example added: https://jsfiddle.net/9eoq22ts/9/

Comment: I need this .hide() because the div is set to display: hidden; in my css. In order for me to get a read out of the actual table height I need to show the div get the height then hide it again. The reason for this being inside the function is eventually this will be a generic function to handle all table dropdowns across all pages.

Comment: @Murph_Fish Please try this example, tell me if anything else you need. https://jsfiddle.net/9eoq22ts/9/

Comment: it was very close but it wasn't showing correctly and the corner pinch hide wasn't working fluidly with my table, However, I do appreciate your input and like the style of that hide very much. +1 for style!